# How to pass custom argument while building WAR

Tags: grails, war

I want to pass a custom argument while building war and want to access that parameter in my controllers, I tried doing this

```
grails war -Dcustom.arg=value1
```

And in controller

```
def customArg = System.getProperty("custom.arg")
```

This works if I do the same with run-app but not with WAR. I think I can achieve this by adding 'custom.arg' argument while starting the Tomcat server but I don't want to do this as I don't have access over the Tomcat servers. So, is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around for this. I used external configuration file and wrote on the file from _Events.groovy file. I created a new file called 'custom-config.properties' file at 'grails-app/config' and added following to config.groovy file

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:custom-config.properties"]
```

I then created _Events.groovy file and added the following

```
eventCompileStart  = { kind ->
    String customConfig = System.getProperty('custom.arg')
    File file = new File('grails-app/conf/custom-config.properties')
    if(brand) file.text = "custom.arg=${customConfig}"
    else file.text = ''
}
```

Now, I can just do this in the controllers

```
grailsApplication.config.custom.arg
```

This works with grails war and grails run-app as long as you pass parameters like this

```
grails war -Dcustom.arg=value1
```

or

```
grails run-app -Dcustom.arg=value1
```

Comment: This answer works for me.  Minor note, once your property file has been set as above, it will continue to have that argument until such time as you manually alter it again. Therefore, if - for example - you don't want your custom.arg's logic to run accidentally in future calls to `grails war` etc.  make sure to have a call that sets `custom.arg` back to `null`